# What part of the soul is reincarnated?

Tags: reincarnation

I know the Ruach is associated with what moves us deeply, when we hear a niggun, or we witness a Jewish tradition, it is our Ruach that is stimulated, recognizing it seems where it comes from.

Can I assume the Ruach is what always comes back when we reincarnate?

Comment: The idea that it is our Ruach that is associated with what moves us deeply is very interesting. Have you seen it written somewhere? Where do you know this from? I would like to know more about this as well

Comment: The Arizal explains that what Rebecca received the ruach of Sarah. And that since we get the Ruach at age 12-13. Sarah passed away when Rebecca was 12. So this confirms that it is the Ruach that reincarnates..

Comment: @mbloch looking for the source

Comment: @mbloch not a source but this is where i read it https://www.rabbidavidcooper.com/cooper-print-index/2010/11/8/2358-five-dimensions-of-the-soul.html